Can I create a method that returns a value, or yields data, based on a switch?
I have this method:
def fetch_rows(connection, return_cursor = False):
    query = f"""SELECT ... """
    cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    cur.execute(query)

    if return_cursor:
        return cur
    else:
        info(f"Found {cur.rowcount} record(s).")
        for row in cur:
            yield row

But, even as I set return_cursor to True in the call, I still get this error when trying to use the returned cursor:

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'rowcount'

Is what I am trying even possible?

No. The presence of yield anywhere in the body makes it into a Generator.

It is unclear why you need fetch_rows to be a generator at all, since the returning cursor is already an iterable.

@blhsing Yes, I saw that too. This is some legacy code and I probably had reasons to do it like this. Or just made a small mistake. Because of legacy, I don't want to touch too much. But knowing that a method with yield can never return, I know what to do now.
